# Throwing an error in ActionScript and catching it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, externalinterface, throw

I am using the ExternalInterface to communicate between Flash and JavaScript using callbacks and the call method. I would like to throw an exception in ActionScript 3.0 and catch it in JavaScript and I was please wondering if there was anyway to do that?

Thank you very much,
Rudy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
try {
     // statements
} catch (error:Error) {
     ExternalInterface.call(functionsName, error.message);
}
```

Where functionsName is the function that will get the error as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you, that's currently what I am doing but I was wondering if there was any way to actually catch the exception in JavaScript rather than rely on the ExternalInterface. I guess there is not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, actionscript works inside a swf file via Flash Player. JS works in a completely different world outside of the swf. Think of the SWF like a Virtual Machine (it actually is more or less).

So basically, you need to handle the error in AS first, other ways there is no way to let JS know.